# How to use ContainsValue in Dictionary of type class

Tags: c#, dictionary

I am creating dictionary of class but I am not able to use "ContainsValue" method. Please help

My Class:

```
 class clsAttendance
    {
        public string TagId { get; set; }
        public DateTime LastFoundDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime CapturedAt { get; set; }
    }
```

My Dictionary:

```
 private Dictionary<int, clsAttendance> dicAttendance = new Dictionary<int, clsAttendance>();
```

I want to check if particular TagId exists in dictionary or not, I am doing like this but not working:

```
clsAttendance clsAtt = new clsAttendance();
clsAtt.TagId = 123456AANN;
//---- Check if RFID exists in dictionary or not
bool rfidExists = dicAttendance.ContainsValue(clsAtt);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your class `clsAttendance` has to override `Equals` or implement `IEquatable<clsAttendance>`. Otherwise it's only found if it's the same reference. Always override also `GethashCode`.

This example shows both which is recommended anyway:

```
public class clsAttendance : IEquatable<clsAttendance>
{
    public string TagId { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastFoundDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime CapturedAt { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        var otherAttendance = obj as clsAttendance;
        if (otherAttendance == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return this.Equals(otherAttendance);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return (this.TagId != null ? this.TagId.GetHashCode() : 0);
    }

    public bool Equals(clsAttendance other)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, other)) return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, other)) return true;
        return string.Equals(this.TagId, other.TagId);
    }
}
```

Comment: How to use this while checking if value exists or not... What method I need to call?

Comment: `icAttendance.ContainsValue(clsAtt);`

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
bool rfidExists = dicAttendance.Values.Any(a => a.TagId.Equals("123456AANN"));
```

Comment: Any other way without using LINQ?

Comment: Yes, see TimSchmelter 's answer :-)

Comment: `foreach (var a in dicAttendance.Values) { if (a.TagId.Equals("123456AANN")) { return true; } } return false;`