# How to use ContainsValue with a Dictionary of Type Class VB .NET

Tags: vb.net, class, dictionary, contains

I have this dictionary: `Dim testDic As New Dictionary(Of String, Items)`

Where `Items` is the following Class:

```
Public Class Items
    Public Property Property1 As String
    Public Property Property2 As String
    Public Sub New()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Question is how to get the key that contains a specific value ("testValue") in Property1.

I tried something like this:

```
testDic.ContainsValue("testValue") 'This line is wrong
```

But it didn't work due to TValue is of Type Class.

Comment: I don't mark your question as a strict duplicate because [here the answer is for C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43995541/how-to-use-containsvalue-in-dictionary-of-type-class) but the reason is the same. Your class needs to implement IEquatable

Comment: There's really no point using `ContainsValue` in this case because it's probably not appropriate to implement `IEquatable` in that type. Just look for the value yourself, i.e. `testDic.Values.Any(Function(v) v.Property1 = "testValue")`. `ContainsValue` does a linear search anyway, so this is not really any less efficient. This way, you don't have to create a dummy instance, either.

Comment: Note that `Any` returns a `Boolean` like `ContainsValue` does. If you actually want the value then call `FirstOrDefault`.

Comment: @Steve you are right. I saw that question before make this one. But as you say is not a strict duplicate, although reason is the same. I was looking for a solution like jmcilhinney provides here.

Comment: @jmcilhinney thanks for that! Now how should I use `FirstOrDefault` in order to get the key value? I need to modify Property2 value which is linked with that key.

Comment: How is `Property2` linked to the key?  You could modify the `Property2` value in the instance directly, but it seems like maybe that's not what you want.

Comment: @Craig for each key TValue is an object with two values in Property1 and Property2. What I want here is modify Property2 for the key value obtained from the "testValue" in Property1.

Comment: @Craig for example, if key value is "testKey" when I look for "testValue" in Property1, then what I want is modify Property2 of the key "testKey". Something like:  `testDic("testKey").Property2 = "modifiedValue"`.

Comment: Do you actually need to know what the key is, though?  Since you're storing a class type, you can just change the `Property2` value on the instance that you get back from `FirstOrDefault` (making sure that you do a check that it `IsNot Nothing` to catch the "Default" part).

Comment: If you really need to do something with the key, then you're probably better off making a secondary reverse index mapping values (or `Property1` values) back to keys or something like that, I don't think there is good support for this usage in the out-of-the-box `Dictionary(Of TKey, TValue)`.